# Signing a private key with android sdk tool

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to sign a private key before releasing the application..  I thought to do it with sdk tool. I enter this command

```
    $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

In cmd , I am at that path.

```
C:\Users\dmitrym\android-sdks\tools
```

But when I run that command I get from the command line,,that the $ keytool..isnt a command..

How do I run that command so that it works? and in which folder will the file be output?

Comment: where did it store the key?!?!

Comment: Alright..found it ..it has worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keytool can be found in your Java/bin directory ("c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\keytool.exe" in my case)
The output should be in the folder you are running from